# How to create a mutable array list containing immutable objects, Java

Tags: java, arraylist, final

I have objects representing columns in a table that I want to declare as final. Some of these columns represent primary keys in my table, and for those columns I want to add them to an array list that gets passed into a function.

How can I declare a mutable list (one that I can add primary key columns to) that contains immutable objects (the column objects themselves)?

Comment: Make the objects immutable by using private and final, then add them into Arraylist

Comment: are u expecting anything else ?

Comment: What is the type of your primary keys?

Comment: @Rishi When I declare the array list, is there a way to know that it will contain immutable objects? Something like `ArrayList<final Column>`

Comment: @MichaelKrause primary keys are also columsn

Comment: no....make the column class variable private and final

Comment: So - your Column class implementation will need to declare all of its fields as final and only provide getters.  Simply declaring a reference to your Column class as final isn't sufficient.

Comment: @MichaelKrause Is there no way to let people reading the code know that they can't change the elements inside the array list aside from comments? I thought there might be some special syntax I could apply to the array list.

Comment: Ah.  Yes.  Use java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList for this.

Comment: @MichaelKrause What?  That has zero effect on the mutability of elements.

Comment: @Michael : He wants to add further objects to list. So it wouldn't be the solution

Comment: @Adam the one and only way to let people know they can't change the elements is to use a class that can't be changed.

Comment: OK, OK.  :)  It seems like what you should do then is add a section to the javadoc for your Column class implementation to indicate that it is immutable.  Documentation only goes so far though.  Having an implementation that has no setters makes it abundantly clear that you can't mutate it.

Comment: Ok, these are all good suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public final class Column {

private final Integer a;
private final String  b;

public Column(Integer a, String b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

public Integer getA() {
    return a;
}

public String getB() {
    return b;
}

}
```

Create column class in this fashion and then add the object to ArrayList.
Check this out : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html